# Compiling hidapi with libusb instead of hidraw

Tags: linux, node.js, compilation, ubuntu-14.04, hidapi

I am trying to compile [hidapi](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi) on ubuntu 14.04 for use with [node-hid](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid). Node-hid cannot see any devices for some reason when hidapi uses hidraw as [this issue](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid/issues/23) describes. The fourth post also offers a solution:

> So, with my limited gcc/waf knowledge I managed to get it to build (I changed wscript to use ../hidapi/libusb/hid.c vs using /hidapi/linux/hid.c. I also changed its linkflags to use -lusb1.0 instead of -ludev and I added /usr/include/libusb-1.0 (a hardcoded path as the makefile wants to use pkgconfig to find that path.. I don't know an equivalent).

I have managed to change /hidapi/linux/hid.c to ../hidapi/libusb/hid.c in the wscript file and I also found the linkflags and changed them; but, I am not sure how to implement the last part about hardcoding the path. Where would I write this path? Or perhaps, is there a better way to get node-hid working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node-hid` doesn't use the wscript anymore, it has a binding.gyp now and so [node-gyp is used instead](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid/blob/52e86668af90781ef0ce0e2e8ef2584a47943f4a/install.sh#L5-L6). Also by default [the binding.gyp uses `libusb` instead of `hidraw`](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid/blob/54d5ae05f5f0415f956c11598db9f0cd883b0d39/binding.gyp#L3), so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You are completely right! Turns out node-hid just doesn't work with the specific device I was testing with.

Comment: Just an update that node-hid^0.7.0 now only uses hidraw. To use libusb, you must downgrade to node-hid@0.6.0. libusb is more stable than hidraw. Weirdly, hidraw only works with high power (red) USB 3.0 ports on my system. libusb works on all.